# SOCI (SQL C++ wrapper) - PostgreSQL doesn't execute commands (?)

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, soci

When i figured out how to compile a simple program, now I have other problem ... I installed PostgreSQL and created database and table:

> 1) createdb testDB 2) create table cities (city varchar(80), location
>   varchar(80));

And my still very simple program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <soci.h>
#include <postgresql/soci-postgresql.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   try
   { 
      soci::session sql(soci::postgresql, "dbname=testDB");

    string row = "";
    sql << "select * from cities;", soci::into(row);

    sql << "insert into cities values('London', 'UK')";

    sql << "select * from cities;", soci::into(row);
    cout << row << "\n"; 
   }
   catch (soci::postgresql_soci_error const & e)
   {
      std::cerr << "PostgreSQL error: " << e.sqlstate() << " " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
   catch (std::exception const & e)
   {
      std::cerr << "Some other error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;

}
```

This code shows me only rows I already have in my testDB and doesn't show a row that I've just inserted. For example: in my testDB, in table cities, I have:

> Warsaw Poland 
>   Berlin Germany 
>   Paris France

and above code shows me:

> Warsaw Poland

but doesn't show:

> Berlin Germany 
>   Paris France
>   London UK

Please, help:(

Comment: How about commit before second select?

Comment: @ForEveR: hm, this code: http://pastie.org/private/y89269ea8u3vhif0m1adcw shows me 'Warsaw' two times ... take a look: http://pastie.org/private/i1ejnzyenmvwgvjios2ja

Comment: @ForEveR: geez, thanks buddy ! ^^ It worked perfectly :D I just added `sql.commit();` after `sql << "insert into cities values('London', 'UK')";` and it's working now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, adding commit after `sql << "insert into cities values ('London', 'UK')";`
solve this problem.